# Decoding Base64 / Quoted Printable encoded UTF8 string

Tags: c#, utf-8, base64, mime, email-headers

In my ASP.Net application working process, I need to do some work with string, which equals something like

```
=?utf-8?B?SWhyZSBCZXN0ZWxsdW5nIC0gVmVyc2FuZGJlc3TDpHRpZ3VuZyAtIDExMDU4OTEyNDY=?=
```

How can I decode it to normal human language?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

`Convert.FromBase64String()` does not work for string, which equals 
`=?UTF-8?Q?Bestellbest=C3=A4tigung?=`

I get `The format of s is invalid. s contains a non-base-64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space-character among the padding characters.` exception.

**Update:**

[**Solution Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2236192/1190932)

[**Alternative solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3095759/1190932)

**Update:**

What kind of string encoding is that: `Nwei&szlig;` ???

Comment: Looks like base64 to me.  Try decoding with base64 and see if that gets you your utf-8 string.

Comment: Nwei&szlig; Is a Html entity, you can decode/encode with HttpUtility.HtmlDecode HttpUtility.HtmlEncode.

Comment: This is a MIME header  (a combination of Quoted-printable & Base64) (note that `-` and `?` cannot be in a Base64 string)  The base64 segment is after `B?` and should be encoded to `utf-8` once the base64 decoding has given you a byte array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be MIME Header Encoding.  The Q in your second example indicates that it is Quoted Printable.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126070/decode-an-utf8-email-header) seems to cover the variants fairly well.  In a quick search I didn't find any .NET libraries to decode this automatically, but it shouldn't be hard to do manually if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a library that will decode these sorts of strings. You can find it at http://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit

Specifically, take a look at `MimeKit.Utils.Rfc2047.DecodeText()`

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a base-64 string:

```
        string zz = "SWhyZSBCZXN0ZWxsdW5nIC0gVmVyc2FuZGJlc3TDpHRpZ3VuZyAtIDExMDU4OTEyNDY=";

        byte[] dd = Convert.FromBase64String(zz);

        // Returns Ihre Bestellung - Versandbestätigung - 1105891246
        string yy = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dd);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an **encoded word**, which is used in email headers when there is non-ASCII content.  Encoded words are defined in RFC 2047:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-2

The BNF for an encoded word is:

```
encoded-word = "=?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?="
```

So the correct way to interpret this is:

1. The data is the stuff between the 3rd and 4th question marks
2. It has been Base64 encoded (the 'B' stands for Base64; if it were a
   'Q' then it would be quoted-printable).
3. Once you decode the
   data, it will be in the UTF-8 character set.

The result, as @Shai correctly pointed out, is:

```
Ihre Bestellung - Versandbestätigung - 1105891246
```

This is German.  The umlaut is obviously the reason for the UTF-8 and thus the need for an encoded word.  The translation is:

```
Your order - Delivery confirmation - 1105891246
```

Apparently it's a tracking number for an order.

All modern email clients (and Outlook) transparently support encoded words.

Answer (score 1):

That's not UTF8. Thats a Base64 encoded string.

the UTF-8 only indicates that the target string is in UTF8 format.
After decoding the Base64 string:

```
SWhyZSBCZXN0ZWxsdW5nIC0gVmVyc2FuZGJlc3TDpHRpZ3VuZyAtIDExMDU4OTEyNDY=
```

You'll get the following result:

```
Ihre Bestellung - Versandbestätigung - 1105891246
```

See [Base64 online decode/encode](http://www.base64decode.org/)

Comment: It's not working for =?UTF-8?Q?Bestellbest=C3=A4tigung?=
Please, see topic update.

Comment: ofcourse it's not working, `=?UTF-8?Q?Bestellbest=C3=A4tigung?=` is not a base64 encoded string.

Comment: It seems, that my task becomes more complicated..
Could you, please, explain, what kind of string is that?
I'm supposed to get "Bestellbestätigung" from it..

Comment: Where do you get that input from?

Comment: I'm getting those strings from Gmail, using ImapX library. E-mails contain German special characters, and it seems, that those chars aren't processed correctly. Can it be culture problem?

Comment: Seems to be MIME Header encoding.  The B is Base 64, the Q is Quoted printable

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a base64 string.

Try Convert.FromBase64String

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx

Answer (score -2):

This is a bit of guesswork, but let's try

- remove `=?` from start and `?=` from end
- keep the start up to the next `?` as the character set
- Remove the `B?` - don't know, what it is
- Convert the rest to a `byte[]` via `System.Convert.FromBase64String()`
- Convert this to the final String via `Encoding.GetSTring()` using the character set remembered in the second step

Comment: A bit of guesswork, sounds like a very good reason not to post an answer.